# Hibernate NamedQuery, set values

Tags: java, hibernate, wrapper

Good evening! I am trying to set values from my query to wrapper class TestWrapper

**TestWrapper class**:

```
package com.bionic.wrappers;

public class TestWrapper {

    private String name;
    private int duration;

    public TestWrapper(){
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Here is **my query**:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getAvailableTestsNames",
    query = "SELECT test.testName, test.duration FROM Result result JOIN   result.test test JOIN result.user user where user.id = :userId"
```

and **DAO class**:

```
    public List<TestWrapper> getAvailableTestsNames(long id){
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("getAvailableTestsNames");
    query.setParameter("userId", id);
    return (List<TestWrapper>)query.getResultList();
}
```

I get an exeption and i see that values won't set appropriate here:

```
    public static Set<TestDTO> convertAvailableTestsToDTO(List<TestWrapper> tests){
    Set<TestDTO> testDTOs = new HashSet<>();
    for (TestWrapper test : tests){
        TestDTO testDTO = new TestDTO(test.getName(), test.getDuration());
        testDTOs.add(testDTO);
    }
    return testDTOs;
}
```

I get an **expeption**:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.bionic.wrappers.TestWrapper
```

Thank you!

Comment: `query.getResultList();` is this exist in Query interface ??

Comment: Can you clarify at the start what is wrong, and what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough context but in the getAvailableTestsNames meth. looks like you're doing a query that returns scalar results by returning "test.testName, test.duration" where you probably just want to return a List of TestWrapper  so the query should just be " from XXX" , you can omit the select field1,field2 ... hibernate does that for you.

See section 11.4.1.3. Scalar results of https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-querying vs. 11.4.1. Executing queries

Hope this helps

Aa.

Comment: I just don't want to overload db with data which i don't need. So i try to get just the fields which i need

Comment: Well your entity has 2 persisted properties so I don't see how that would overload.  Give it a try.  Otherwise see 11.4.1.3 for what to next when querying just for 2 column. Cheers